# Error: Failed to execute SSH command in PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I do have below code. My objective is to connect to a remote server when msisdn and date has provided and get some details. To test this script I have turned of SeLinux also.

The issue is with $ssh_command = 'ssh omcuser@10.18.16.166'. I am always getting an error as `Error: Failed to execute SSH command` due to sshoutout is null.

am I doing any thin wrong here?(other commands are working, like ls -ltr etc.)

```
<?php

    
    if ($_POST) {
      $msisdn = $_POST["msisdn"];
      $date = $_POST["date"];
    
 
      if (empty($msisdn)) {
        echo "<p>Error: MSISDN field is required.</p>";
      }
    

      elseif (empty($date) || !preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/', $date)) {
        echo "<p>Error: Date field is required and should be in YYYY-MM-DD format.</p>";
      }
    
     
      else {
        $old_path = getcwd();
        chdir('/var/www/html/check');
        $output = shell_exec('./test.sh $msisdn $date 2>&1');
        chdir($old_path);
        if (strpos($output, 'Permission denied') !== false) {
          echo "<p>Error: Permission denied. Check directory permissions.</p>";
        } elseif ($output === null) {
          echo "<p>Error executing script.</p>";
        } else {
          // Connect to the remote server via SSH and execute a command
          $ssh_command = 'ssh omcuser@10.18.16.166';
          $ssh_output = shell_exec($ssh_command);
          
          if ($ssh_output === null) {
            echo "<p>Error: Failed to execute SSH command.</p>";
          } else {
            echo "<pre>$ssh_output</pre>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
    
    <html>
    <body>
      <form action="dashboard.php" method="post">
        MSISDN: <input type="text" name="msisdn"><br>
        Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Missing `'` on line `chdir('/var/www/html/check);` (you can see where the syntax highlighting breaks)

Comment: It is a typo..corrected...@Phil

Comment: If your SSH command requires any input (e.g. username and password or terminal input) I don't know if shell_exec will be enough to use it. You might need to use [proc open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and pipe a stream that can allow you to input data to the process.

Comment: "due to sshoutout is null" -- how do you know?